# how to add second axes to chart JS

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have a combination of bar line chart JS and it has only one axes. what I want to do is to add a second axes on the right. image for code result with only one axes in the below link. Just want to know how can I add a second axes and set its values

[image for code result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TNnonL_nlQOvkXgyYf09_rWzrsUpZIk8/view?usp=sharing)

my code below for the bar line chart
html code:

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Chart.js Combo Bar Line Chart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div style="width: 50%">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
'use strict';

window.chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    brown: 'rgb(237, 125, 49)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgb(91,155,213)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};

(function(global) {
    var Months = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'
    ];

    var COLORS = [
        '#4dc9f6',
        '#f67019',
        '#f53794',
        '#537bc4',
        '#acc236',
        '#166a8f',
        '#00a950',
        '#58595b',
        '#8549ba'
    ];

    var Samples = global.Samples || (global.Samples = {});
    var Color = global.Color;

    Samples.utils = {
        // Adapted from http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/
        srand: function(seed) {
            this._seed = seed;
        },

        rand: function(min, max) {
            var seed = this._seed;
            min = min === undefined ? 0 : min;
            max = max === undefined ? 1 : max;
            this._seed = (seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
            return min + (this._seed / 233280) * (max - min);
        },

        numbers: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var min = cfg.min || 0;
            var max = cfg.max || 1;
            var from = cfg.from || [];
            var count = cfg.count || 8;
            var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
            var continuity = cfg.continuity || 1;
            var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
            var data = [];
            var i, value;

            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                value = (from[i] || 0) + this.rand(min, max);
                if (this.rand() <= continuity) {
                    data.push(Math.round(dfactor * value) / dfactor);
                } else {
                    data.push(null);
                }
            }

            return data;
        },

        labels: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var min = cfg.min || 0;
            var max = cfg.max || 100;
            var count = cfg.count || 8;
            var step = (max - min) / count;
            var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
            var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
            var prefix = cfg.prefix || '';
            var values = [];
            var i;

            for (i = min; i < max; i += step) {
                values.push(prefix + Math.round(dfactor * i) / dfactor);
            }

            return values;
        },

        months: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var count = cfg.count || 12;
            var section = cfg.section;
            var values = [];
            var i, value;

            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                value = Months[Math.ceil(i) % 12];
                values.push(value.substring(0, section));
            }

            return values;
        },

        color: function(index) {
            return COLORS[index % COLORS.length];
        },

        transparentize: function(color, opacity) {
            var alpha = opacity === undefined ? 0.5 : 1 - opacity;
            return Color(color).alpha(alpha).rgbString();
        }
    };

    // DEPRECATED
    window.randomScalingFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Samples.utils.rand(0, 100));
    };

    // INITIALIZATION

    Samples.utils.srand(Date.now());

    // Google Analytics
    /* eslint-disable */
    if (document.location.hostname.match(/^(www\.)?chartjs\.org$/)) {
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-28909194-3', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    }
    /* eslint-enable */

}(this));        
        var chartData = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [{
                type: 'line',
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                data: [
                   '80',
                    '80',
                    '80',
                   '80',
                    '80',
                    '80','80'
                ]
            }, 
              {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'Dataset 2',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                borderColor: 'white',
                borderWidth: 2
            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'Dataset 3',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.brown,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ]
            }]

        };
        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart.js Combo Bar Line Chart'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: true
                    },scales: {
            xAxes: [{ barPercentage: 0.3 }],xAxes: [{ beginAtZero: true }]
        }
                }
            });
        };

        document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', 
          function() {
            chartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
                    return randomScalingFactor();
                });
            });
            window.myMixedChart.update();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You where redefining and thus overriding your `xAxes` config a second time, if you change it to `yAxes` and add 2 objects in there you get 2 `y` axes, on the second on you can set `position: 'right'` to get it to the right of the chart, you only need to specify its ID in the right dataset to link that dataset to that y axis

Example:

```js
window.chartColors = {
  red: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
  orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
  brown: 'rgb(237, 125, 49)',
  green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
  blue: 'rgb(91,155,213)',
  purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
  grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};

(function(global) {
  var Months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
  ];

  var COLORS = [
    '#4dc9f6',
    '#f67019',
    '#f53794',
    '#537bc4',
    '#acc236',
    '#166a8f',
    '#00a950',
    '#58595b',
    '#8549ba'
  ];

  var Samples = global.Samples || (global.Samples = {});
  var Color = global.Color;

  Samples.utils = {
    // Adapted from http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/
    srand: function(seed) {
      this._seed = seed;
    },

    rand: function(min, max) {
      var seed = this._seed;
      min = min === undefined ? 0 : min;
      max = max === undefined ? 1 : max;
      this._seed = (seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
      return min + (this._seed / 233280) * (max - min);
    },

    numbers: function(config) {
      var cfg = config || {};
      var min = cfg.min || 0;
      var max = cfg.max || 1;
      var from = cfg.from || [];
      var count = cfg.count || 8;
      var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
      var continuity = cfg.continuity || 1;
      var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
      var data = [];
      var i, value;

      for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        value = (from[i] || 0) + this.rand(min, max);
        if (this.rand() <= continuity) {
          data.push(Math.round(dfactor * value) / dfactor);
        } else {
          data.push(null);
        }
      }

      return data;
    },

    labels: function(config) {
      var cfg = config || {};
      var min = cfg.min || 0;
      var max = cfg.max || 100;
      var count = cfg.count || 8;
      var step = (max - min) / count;
      var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
      var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
      var prefix = cfg.prefix || '';
      var values = [];
      var i;

      for (i = min; i < max; i += step) {
        values.push(prefix + Math.round(dfactor * i) / dfactor);
      }

      return values;
    },

    months: function(config) {
      var cfg = config || {};
      var count = cfg.count || 12;
      var section = cfg.section;
      var values = [];
      var i, value;

      for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        value = Months[Math.ceil(i) % 12];
        values.push(value.substring(0, section));
      }

      return values;
    },

    color: function(index) {
      return COLORS[index % COLORS.length];
    },

    transparentize: function(color, opacity) {
      var alpha = opacity === undefined ? 0.5 : 1 - opacity;
      return Color(color).alpha(alpha).rgbString();
    }
  };

  // DEPRECATED
  window.randomScalingFactor = function() {
    return Math.round(Samples.utils.rand(0, 100));
  };

  // INITIALIZATION

  Samples.utils.srand(Date.now());

  // Google Analytics
  /* eslint-disable */
  if (document.location.hostname.match(/^(www\.)?chartjs\.org$/)) {
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
      i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
      }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
      a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
      a.async = 1;
      a.src = g;
      m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-28909194-3', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
  /* eslint-enable */

}(this));
var chartData = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
      type: 'line',
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
      borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: [
        '80',
        '80',
        '80',
        '80',
        '80',
        '80', '80'
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor()
      ],
      borderColor: 'white',
      borderWidth: 2
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      yAxisID: 'secondYAxis', // LINK DATASET TO AXIS
      backgroundColor: window.chartColors.brown,
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor()
      ]
    }
  ]

};
window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Combo Bar Line Chart'
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: true
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 0.3
          },
          {
            id: 'secondYAxis',
            position: 'right'
          }
        ],
        xAxes: [{
          beginAtZero: true,
          barPercentage: 0.3
        }]
      }
    }
  });
};

document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    chartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
      dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
        return randomScalingFactor();
      });
    });
    window.myMixedChart.update();
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js'></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Comment: thats it thank you! but can I just know from you where should I identify the start value and the end value of my X axes and Y axes?

Comment: in the `ticks` sub config of the axis object you can set the `min` and `max` property: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/category.html#min-max-configuration, https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/linear.html#axis-range-settings